# Angular5/6: IE uses old build and doesn't fetch latest build

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular-cli

I have an angular application that I have been developing with angular5. When I make changes and deploy it on a server, Chrome is able to fetch the latest build with clear cache/cookies. But for IE, I need to clear cache/cookies. This is going to be a problem, because Once I deliver it to production, If I provide a new build, they would still see the old build.

Comment: So is your question, how to prevent IE from caching files on new angular builds?

Comment: Here is an answer : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4320

Comment: @Daniel yes. That's right